# Manhwa where a red-haired girl is transported into a game

Tags: story-identification, manga

In this manhwa the girl had red hair and was transported to the world of a video game (or novel, I'm not sure).  She has to survive; there were various men in the game and she had to gain their trust/love to stay alive. I think she was the villain in the game,

It is not the manhwa "it was all a mistake" or "Rien qu'illusion"

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?  What is the game/novel setting: modern world, mediaeval, classical, etc.?

Answer (score 2):

This could be [Villains are destined to die](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/villains-are-destined-to-die).

All points match your description:
The protagonist is reincarnated/transported into her favorite video game as the villain, she has to raise the opinion of several characters to prevent her death and her hair is red/dark pink.